# Строка или число в string?

Tags: javascript, html

Пользователь вводит данные:

```js
//В скрипте пытаюсь рассуждать,что если это не строка, то выводить ошибку
var registration = document.getElementById("registration");
registration.onclick = function() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  if (typeof(name) === "string") {
    alert("Вы зарегистрированы");
  } else {
    var nameColor = document.getElementById("name");
    nameColor.style.borderColor = "#FF0000";
    alert('Имя введено некорректно')
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Введите имя:
  <input id="name">
</p>
<button id="registration">Зарегистрироваться</button>
```

И собственно вопрос: как в input узнать, что ввел пользователь: число или  строку? К примеру: "12421" и "acaca". Как разделить первый и второй пример?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Input[type="text"]` всегда возвращает символы в качестве строки, хоть вы и можете написать там одни цифры. Для такой валидации лучше использовать [регулярные выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```js
var registration = document.getElementById("registration");
registration.onclick = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("name");
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if (input.value.match(letters)) {
    alert("Вы зарегистрированы");
  } else {
    input.style.borderColor = "#FF0000";
    alert('Имя введено некорректно');
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Введите имя:</div>
<input type="text" id="name">
<button id="registration">Зарегистрироваться</button>
```

Comment: В JS миллион разных способов проверить input на ввод числа и регулярные выражения далеко не самый лучший способ

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев а какой лучше ?

Answer (score 6):

```js
function stringOrNumber(str) {
  if (isNaN(str)) {
    return "string";
  } else {
    return "number";
  }
}

console.log(stringOrNumber("12421"));
console.log(stringOrNumber("acaca"));
```

Comment: Плюс немного лишний.

Answer (score 3):

А можно вообще без скрипта, использовать атрибут `pattern` )

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="^[a-zA-Z]$" title="Разрешаются только английские буквы.">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

В `JavaScript` есть оператор `typeof`:

```
typeof undefined // "undefined"

typeof 0 // "number"

typeof true // "boolean"

typeof "foo" // "string"

typeof {} // "object"

typeof null // "object"

typeof function(){} // "function"
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть много разных способов проверки строки на число, всё зависит от конкретной задачи, например, с помощь функции Number. Приведу несколько примеров (сначала код потом результат):

```
Number('wrwet');
NaN

Number('1.3');
1.3

Number('1e3');
1000
```

Как видно эта функция хорошо справляется с задачей, НО она пропускает экспоненциальную форму записи числа, а такой вариант зачастую не подходит.

Можно добавить проверку, является ли значение конечным числом.
Лично я обычно делаю такую проверку:

```js
if( !isNaN('1e1000') && isFinite('1e1000') ) {
  console.log( 'конечное число');
} else {
  console.log( 'не число (или очень большое число или Infinity');
}
```

Ещё важно учитывать должно ли число быть целим или может быть вещественным, может ли оно быть отрицательным или только положительным.