# Не выводится значение из input

Tags: javascript

Недавно начал изучать JS, перешел к функциям, в частности к return  и столкнулся с такой проблемой.

```js
let num = document.querySelector('input').value;
let btn = document.querySelector('button');

function suma(a) {
  return (a * a);
}
btn.onclick = () => {
  console.log(suma(num));
}
```

```html
<input /><button>Click</button>
```

console возвращает 0, я знаю что значение можно вывести по другому, используя анонимную функцию, без всего этого. Но мне для обучения надо узнать, почему таким способом не получается, тем более, если в переменную num записать просто число, то все сработает.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1039308/302918

Answer (score 3):

Вы считываете значение из инпута во время загрузки страницы, когда он пустой.

```js
let num = document.querySelector('input');
let btn = document.querySelector('button');

function suma(a) {
  return (a * a);
}
btn.onclick = () => {
  console.log(suma(+num.value));
}
```

```html
<input /><button>Click</button>
```